CPU running well under maximum frequency
I use my computer for very CPU intense simulations, but no matter what I do the actual CPU frequency wont ever come close to hardware capacity.
I have an i9-13900K, which maximum CPU freq. is 5.8GHz. I've checked that I am using the performance governor and have turbo mode activated, but the CPU won't get past 4.5GHz (stress test ran using stress --cpu 8 on top of some of the simulations i was talking about):

i7z's output:

turbostat's output:
turbostat version 2023.03.17 - Len Brown <lenb@kernel.org>
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-35-generic root=UUID=03d4508b-01b6-4ec9-ad4e-0070ea58aed9 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
CPUID(0): GenuineIntel 0x20 CPUID levels
CPUID(1): family:model:stepping 0x6:b7:1 (6:183:1) microcode 0x11e
CPUID(0x80000000): max_extended_levels: 0x80000008
CPUID(1): SSE3 MONITOR SMX EIST TM2 TSC MSR ACPI-TM HT TM
CPUID(6): APERF, TURBO, DTS, PTM, HWP, HWPnotify, HWPwindow, HWPepp, HWPpkg, EPB
cpu0: MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE: 0x00850089 (TCC EIST MWAIT PREFETCH TURBO)
CPUID(7): No-SGX Hybrid
CPUID(0x15): eax_crystal: 2 ebx_tsc: 156 ecx_crystal_hz: 38400000
TSC: 2995 MHz (38400000 Hz * 156 / 2 / 1000000)
CPUID(0x16): base_mhz: 3000 max_mhz: 5800 bus_mhz: 100
cpu0: MSR_MISC_PWR_MGMT: 0x000030c2 (ENable-EIST_Coordination ENable-EPB DISable-OOB)
RAPL: 2097 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 125 Watts
cpu0: MSR_PLATFORM_INFO: 0x8080838f1811e00
8 * 100.0 = 800.0 MHz max efficiency frequency
30 * 100.0 = 3000.0 MHz base frequency
cpu0: MSR_IA32_POWER_CTL: 0x00c4005f (C1E auto-promotion: ENabled)
cpu0: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x3737373737373a3a
55 * 100.0 = 5500.0 MHz max turbo 8 active cores
55 * 100.0 = 5500.0 MHz max turbo 7 active cores
55 * 100.0 = 5500.0 MHz max turbo 6 active cores
55 * 100.0 = 5500.0 MHz max turbo 5 active cores
55 * 100.0 = 5500.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
55 * 100.0 = 5500.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
58 * 100.0 = 5800.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
58 * 100.0 = 5800.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
cpu0: MSR_SECONDARY_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x0000002b
43 * 100.0 = 4300.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
cpu0: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_NOMINAL: 0x0000001e (base_ratio=30)
cpu0: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_1: 0x00000000 ()
cpu0: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_2: 0x00000000 ()
cpu0: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_CONTROL: 0x80000000 ( lock=1)
cpu0: MSR_TURBO_ACTIVATION_RATIO: 0x00000000 (MAX_NON_TURBO_RATIO=0 lock=0)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_CST_CONFIG_CONTROL: 0x74008008 (UNdemote-C1, demote-C1, locked, pkg-cstate-limit=8 (unlimited))
Uncore Frequency pkg0 die0: 800 - 5000 MHz (800 - 5000 MHz)
/dev/cpu_dma_latency: 2000000000 usec (default)
current_driver: intel_idle
current_governor: menu
current_governor_ro: menu
cpu0: POLL: CPUIDLE CORE POLL IDLE
cpu0: C1ACPI: ACPI FFH MWAIT 0x0
cpu0: C2ACPI: ACPI FFH MWAIT 0x21
cpu0: C3ACPI: ACPI FFH MWAIT 0x60
cpu0: cpufreq driver: intel_pstate
cpu0: cpufreq governor: performance
cpufreq intel_pstate no_turbo: 0
cpu0: MSR_MISC_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00000000 (L2-Prefetch L2-Prefetch-pair L1-Prefetch L1-IP-Prefetch)
cpu0: MSR_PM_ENABLE: 0x00000001 (HWP)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_CAPABILITIES: 0x01152746 (high 70 guar 39 eff 21 low 1)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_REQUEST: 0x00004646 (min 70 max 70 des 0 epp 0x0 window 0x0 pkg 0x0)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_REQUEST_PKG: 0x8000ff01 (min 1 max 255 des 0 epp 0x80 window 0x0)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_INTERRUPT: 0x00000001 (EN_Guaranteed_Perf_Change, Dis_Excursion_Min)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_STATUS: 0x00000004 (No-Guaranteed_Perf_Change, Excursion_Min)
cpu0: EPB: 6 (balanced)
cpu0: MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT: 0x000a0e03 (0.125000 Watts, 0.000061 Joules, 0.000977 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_INFO: 0x000003e8 (125 W TDP, RAPL 0 - 0 W, 0.000000 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT: 0x4207e800608640 (UNlocked)
cpu0: PKG Limit #1: ENabled (200.000 Watts, 80.000000 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: PKG Limit #2: DISabled (253.000 Watts, 0.002441* sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_VR_CURRENT_CONFIG: 0x00000be0
cpu0: PKG Limit #4: 380.000000 Watts (UNlocked)
cpu0: MSR_DRAM_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: DRAM Limit: DISabled (0.000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POLICY: 9
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: Cores Limit: DISabled (0.000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POLICY: 13
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: GFX Limit: DISabled (0.000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x06641400 (100 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_STATUS: 0x88150c00 (79 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_INTERRUPT: 0x02000003 (100 C, 100 C)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC3_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC6_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC7_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC8_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC9_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)
cpu0: MSR_PKGC10_IRTL: 0x00000000 (NOTvalid, 0 ns)

Core    CPU Avg_MHz Busy%   Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz IPC IRQ SMI POLL    C1ACPI  C2ACPI  C3ACPI  POLL%   C1ACPI% C2ACPI% C3ACPI% CPU%c1  CPU%c6  CPU%c7  CoreTmp CoreThr PkgTmp  GFX%rc6 GFXMHz  GFXAMHz Totl%C0 Any%C0  GFX%C0  CPUGFX% Pkg%pc2 Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 Pkg%pc7 Pkg%pc8 Pkg%pc9 Pk%pc10 CPU%LPI SYS%LPI PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt PKG_%   RAM_%   UncMHz
-   -   3009    74.99   3977    3023    0.72    37046   0   352 522 2597    2758    0.01    0.15    4.63    20.29   25.01   0.00    0.00    82  15058   81  101.10  700 700 2414.36 100.60  0.41    0.41    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    163.48  149.60  0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    3300
0   0   1335    28.38   4703    2995    0.77    1681    0   1   49  496 503 0.00    0.31    34.86   36.42   71.62   0.00    0.00    77  559 81  99.44   700 700 2396.16 99.84   0.40    0.40    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    160.78  147.13  0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00    3300
0   1   3402    72.36   4702    2995    0.81    1484    0   30  4   212 166 0.04    0.03    15.15   12.32   27.64
4   2   3706    78.81   4703    2995    0.93    1100    0   0   1   56  37  0.00    0.02    3.11    17.89   21.19   0.00    0.00    76  620
4   3   1010    21.49   4700    2995    0.92    725 0   156 77  212 214 0.10    0.75    12.45   65.28   78.51
8   4   1098    23.37   4697    2995    0.89    647 0   0   55  206 193 0.00    0.43    9.54    66.62   76.63   0.00    0.00    79  3618
8   5   3700    78.67   4703    2995    0.91    1107    0   0   6   58  39  0.00    0.03    2.76    18.36   21.33
12  6   2301    49.01   4694    2995    0.74    822 0   0   20  74  111 0.00    0.30    4.35    46.23   50.99   0.00    0.00    78  964
12  7   2432    51.64   4710    2995    0.77    948 0   100 65  160 143 0.08    0.41    7.73    40.11   48.36
16  8   1497    31.79   4710    2995    0.75    677 0   60  28  177 146 0.01    0.45    8.22    59.48   68.21   0.00    0.00    82  3290
16  9   3230    68.72   4699    2995    0.77    996 0   0   27  40  70  0.00    0.19    2.57    28.36   31.28
20  10  2444    52.00   4700    2995    0.85    1061    0   5   20  148 188 0.01    0.11    8.52    39.26   48.00   0.00    0.00    80  4611
20  11  2315    49.21   4705    2995    0.78    882 0   0   83  181 128 0.00    0.49    7.81    42.39   50.79
24  12  4688    99.70   4703    2995    0.85    1303    0   0   0   1   0   0.00    0.00    0.07    0.00    0.30    0.00    0.00    82  4448
24  13  41  0.87    4698    2995    0.92    607 0   0   36  331 341 0.00    0.42    18.12   80.61   99.13
28  14  4366    92.81   4704    2995    0.80    1291    0   0   10  33  41  0.00    0.11    1.08    5.78    7.19    0.00    0.00    78  15058
28  15  381 8.11    4692    2995    0.77    659 0   0   41  212 438 0.00    0.68    9.67    81.55   91.89
32  16  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.68    1393    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    78  101
33  17  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.63    1310    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    78  101
34  18  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.72    1309    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    78  101
35  19  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.70    1310    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    78  101
36  20  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.75    1309    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    77  31
37  21  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.53    1309    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    77  31
38  22  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.78    1310    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    77  31
39  23  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.54    1309    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    77  31
40  24  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.53    1309    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    76  0
41  25  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.54    1309    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    76  0
42  26  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.57    1310    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    76  0
43  27  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.70    1309    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    76  0
44  28  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.71    1328    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    73  0
45  29  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.78    1309    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    73  0
46  30  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.57    1312    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    73  0
47  31  3598    99.77   3606    2995    0.53    1311    0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.23    0.00    0.00    73  0

I've seen the temperature get to like 84C but never past that (my understanding is that this indicates temperature isnt the bottleneck, but correct me if im wrong).
Any ideas on what the problem could be or how to improve things?
Cheers

I don't know what i7z is, what does turbostat return?

@ArtemS.Tashkinov added to the post!

The 13900K has a base TDP of 125W, you're well above it - 163W - this could be the reason.

Please try kernel 6.9.2. Intel might have changed a few things here and there.

Cool, thanks for the help I wouldnt have known what to look for. Do you think this is something that could be solved by changing settings or drivers or is it a hardware issue? My fan is not running on full speed anyway so I am unsure whether changing it would improve things?

@ArtemS.Tashkinov Will do! Would replacing the cooling system perhaps help as well?

I'd first try the same workload on Windows and check the clocks using e.g. CoreTemp or HWiNFO64 or whatever works for you. That will eliminate any HW related issues.

This is expected: Turbo mode is only possible if you're using only a subset of cores, or for very short terms. You're using all cores, and you look at it over human, i.e., very long terms.
That's the thing about thermal design limits: you can't cheat them for long.

You don't even know what their workload is. And their temps are well below thermal limits.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov that's the thing about thermal design: it doesn't care about the computational specifics. You can't get more than X watt of heat away from the package. That's why there's "turbo" at all (instead of just raising the "normal" max speed). "Turbo" is explicitly what you can achieve only if you're not doing it on all cores, or only for short.

What weirds me out is that I have people at my lab with worse CPU's that run closer to capacity (higher freqs than 4.5GHz)... Doing the same task as well. Isn't that an indication that something is wrong and preventing mine from achieving the same speed?

Although Ive also noticed that they get lower temps as well (bellow 70). My experience is that this kind of workload should stress the CPU to like 90 degrees before throttling, but that was also on a windows machine, I dont know how things might be different on linux
